# Вызов функции по keyup через промежуток времени

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть `input` при вводе в который срабатывает функция.

Как сделать, чтобы функция срабатывала не сразу (непосредственно при вводе) а только через интервал времени, после того как мы завершим ввод.

Пробовал с `setTimeout`, функция действительно начинала срабатывать через интервал времени, но не до того как я закончил ввод.

А мне как раз надо чтобы функция сработала, только в конце, чтобы она извлекла полное значение из поля. А не обрабатывала его по частям по мере срабатывания `keyup`

`change` тоже не подходит, так как input может не потерять фокус, но пользователь все таки должен увидеть результат через 1-2 сек.

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
  val = $(this).val();
  $('.output').text(val);
});
```

```css
.output {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  width: 350px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: А как вы определите, что пользователь закончил вводить в input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё просто: при вводе нужно не только ставить новый таймер, но и отменять старый. Для этого есть функция [`clearTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp). Вот код:

```js
// Текущий таймер
var MyTimer = null;

// При печати
$('input').keyup(function() {
    // Сохранить текст
    var val = $(this).val();

    // Остановить старый таймер, если есть
    if (MyTimer !== null)
        clearTimeout(MyTimer);

    // Поставить новый таймер
    MyTimer = setTimeout(
        function () { $('.output').text(val); },
        1000
    );
});
```

```css
.output {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  width: 350px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<div class="output"></div>
```